# How can we organize some tag cleaning?

Tags: discussion, tags

### To organize the work I propose to do one letter by answer (eventually regourping letter with one or two occurences of tag)

---

When I want to tag some question I often fall on tag without description and this can be very annoying.

For example [resolution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resolution):
 resolution of what problem ? screen ?
or even worth [size](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/size):
 you can have a size for everything, and as much as size matters tagging correctly question also matters
It isn't possible to force people who create new tags to add a definition even small because obviously there is some serious issue with some.

Maybe a campaign of definition and (eventually) suppression could be launch to solve some tagging issues ?

**Edit 1:**
I also find [graphics](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics) [group](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group) once at least assiociated with [lvm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lvm)  and  [string](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) what is the point of tag [string](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) when there is already text processing [awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/awk) [sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sed) [ed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ed) [vi](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vi) tags...

**Edit 2:**
Finally watch the 12 last tag created:
[image: 12 last created tag snapshot]

There are only 3 description, and one tag is [advanced](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advanced). 
What does that mean ? is it a tool ? a software ? or just an *advanced question* ?

Comment: This is a good initiative but **please** do not add definitions to the tag descriptions, that is **not** what they're for! If you want to do this kind of work (and that's great), read [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/improved-tagging/). The excerpt should not be a definition unless it is an obscure concept, it should instead be an explanation of when this tag should be used.

Comment: @terdon ok I will take this in consideration, also thank you for the tag edit link, I didn't know how to make a tag link. Also there is just in letter A very stange question and eitheir wiki and excerpt are almost impossible to write without the input of others, like tag /advanced. I will continu to update the list and write excerpt and wiki if possible but I can't define some tag and they should be define

Comment: We do need to organize some tag cleaning but this isn't the way to do it. It's impossible to review a monster thread like this. If there's discussion to be had about a tag, it needs a separate meta question, one per tag or group of closely-related tags. We don't need a discussion for every tag, for example [tag:advanced] is very obviously a meta tag and should be removed.

Comment: [tag:resolution] is used pretty consistently for what it was intended, which is display resolution, but it wouldn't hurt to rename the tag to [tag:screen-resolution] or [tag:display-resolution]. [tag:size] is about the size of something; while it doesn't make sense on its own, it has an objective meaning, so it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Letter A

**No defintion (and often not used more than 2 or three time)**

- [ack](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ack)  **definition added**
- [audacious](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audacious) **definition added**
- [aufs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aufs) **definition added**
- [auditd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/auditd) **definition added**
- [ansible](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ansible)  **definition added**
- [aspell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aspell)  **definition added**
- [anaconda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anaconda)  **Excerpt added**
- [application](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/application)  **is about to be deleted**
- [asp.net](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp.net)
- [async](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/async)  *async should be either deleted or really precisely define because lots of thing can be asynchronous*
- [autocmd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autocmd) Suggested: *Automated action extension of VIM*
- [ati](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ati)
- [atime](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atime)
- [atom](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atom)
- [auto-complete](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/auto-complete) which is synonym of autocomplete synonym of autocompletion
- [autoconf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autoconf)
- [autoreconf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autoreconf)
- [autocorrection](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autocorrection)
- [automake](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automake)
- [autojump](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autojump)
- [autologin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autologin)
- [apt-get](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apt-get)
- [arch](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arch)
- [array](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array)
- [arp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arp)
- [arithmetic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic)
- [archive](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/archive)
- [ansi-term](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ansi-term)
- [animation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animation)
- [autorepeat](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autorepeat)
- [autoplay](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autoplay)
- [avconv](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avconv)
- [axel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/axel)
- [android-terminal-emulator](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-terminal-emulator) (obvious thought)

**very strange**

- [administration](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/administration) most of post talks about admin issue or user issue this tag is too brood
- [advanced](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advanced) **deleted**
- [akwextlib](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/akwextlib) What ?
- [alternate-screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternate-screen)
- [amusements](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amusements) it speaks for itself
- [access-point](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/access-point) access point to what and how ? is it that important ?
- [accounts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accounts) there is already a tag `/users` more documented
- [appearance](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/appearance) Why not but what does it mean ?
- [authorization](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/authorization) It seems really unclear in my here as you can set up an authorization for pretty much everything
- [art](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/art) **deleted**

  feel free to complete the list

Comment: I haven't gone through all your list, there's just too much stuff. [tag:authorization] caught my eye: it's a clear concept (if not very well understood to people without a security background), see [Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/authorization).

Comment: @Gilles hope you get some sleep, I understand what an authorization is but it miss an excerpt because it's used for so different topics

Answer (score 0):

## Letter B

#### no complete yet I will add the rest in a while

**Excerpt missing**
[background](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/background)  use for wallpaper and background task
[bandwidth](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bandwidth)
[base64](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/base64)
[basename](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/basename) I propose: *POSIX binary to get the basename of a path*
[bc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bc) I propose: *An arbitrary precision calculator language*
[bell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bell)
[binary](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binary)
[bind10](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bind10)
[block](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/block) imperative because use for 2 very different meaning

**Excerpt incorrect**
[badblocks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/badblocks)

**No problem**

[bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bash) [bashrc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bashrc) [bash-script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bash-script) [backlight](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backlight) [backspace](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backspace)  [battery](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery)[bazaar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bazaar)
[bcache](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bcache)
[benchmark](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/benchmark)
[bind](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bind)
[binfmt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binfmt)
[bioinformatics](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bioinformatics)
[bios](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bios)
[bittorrent](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bittorrent)